# How can I move the bounding circle of an object?

Tags: edit-mode

I have a problem with the bounding circle in bge. I have a rigid body object with a hole on it and is is placed on a static box. I want to be able to get in but I can't due to the position of the bounding circle in the middle of it.I tried to change the radius but then it cannot stay still on the box . How can I move the bounding circle? [image]

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Please add additional information regarding your project and if possible some screenshots.

Comment: Is it clear now?

Comment: You need to move the origin to actual mesh, or visa versa.

Comment: You mean origin to geometry?